# Customize gradle task properties when dependsOn

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I created custom task which should process output of gradle `dependencies` task ( exactly `./gradlew dependencies --configuration myFlavorDebugRuntimeClasspath`). I want to create my custom task for every buildVariant (`PassportGenerateTask passportGen = project.tasks.create("pasportGenerate${variantName}", PassportGenerateTask)`).

But i cant customize dependenciesReportTask properties for every passportGen. When i call passportGen for speciefic buildVariant it use dependenciesReportTask.setProperty("configurations", ...) of last build variant among all (project.android.applicationVariants.all).

For examlpe if I have following build variants (googleDebug googleRelease samsungDebug samsungRelease) and call passportGen task (`./gradlew pasportGenerateGoogleDebug`) it will use wrong properties for dependenciesReportTask (configuration will be samsungReleaseRuntimeClasspath configuration )

```
class AppPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {


    void apply(Project project) {

        project.afterEvaluate {
            // Create tasks for each Build Variant
            project.android.applicationVariants.all { ApplicationVariant variant ->
                def variantName = variant.name.capitalize()
                def variantOutput = variant.outputs.first()



                //Generating configuration name for dependency report
                def configurationName = ""
                if (variant.productFlavors.size() > 0) {
                    configurationName += variant.productFlavors.get(0).name
                    configurationName += variant.getBuildType().name.capitalize()
                } else {
                    configurationName += variant.getBuildType().name
                }
                configurationName += "RuntimeClasspath"

                def configurations = project.configurations.collect()

                configurations.removeAll {
                    !it.name.equals(configurationName)
                }


                //prepare file for output of "dependencies" tasks
                def depReportFileName = "dependeciesReport${variantName}.txt"
                def dependenciesReportOutputFile = new File(depReportFileName)


                //Get "dependencies" task from all project tasks
                def dependenciesReportTask = project.tasks["dependencies"]
                dependenciesReportTask.setProperty("configurations", configurations)
                dependenciesReportTask.setProperty("outputFile", dependenciesReportOutputFile)


                //create cutom task for every buildVariant which depends on "dependencies" task
                PassportGenerateTask passportGen = project.tasks.create("pasportGenerate${variantName}", PassportGenerateTask)
                passportGen.variant = variant
                passportGen.configuration = configurations.collect().get(0)

                //add dependency on "dependencies"
                passportGen.dependsOn dependenciesReportTask

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only way i can achieve what i want is call:

```
def dependenciesReportTask = project.tasks["dependencies"]
dependenciesReportTask.setProperty("configurations", configurations)
dependenciesReportTask.setProperty("outputFile", dependenciesReport)
dependenciesReportTask.execute()
```

inside my custom PassportGenerateTask task main action method (@TaskAction) but calling execute inside other task is deprecated feature and will be removed in gradle 5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not only deprecated, it is purely internal implementation detail that most probably does **not** do what you expect it does and almost always produces many more problems than it tries to solve and actually fails.

You most probably also shouldn't rape the `dependencies` task. If you need multiple such tasks with different configuration, simply create new tasks of type `DependencyReportTask` and configure them however you like.

Comment: I use 'dependencies' because it can generate dependencies report file for speciefic configuration. I use this report file in my 'PassportGenerateTask'. How can I create dependencies report file inside 'DependencyReportTask'?

Comment: `dependencies` is a task of type `DependencyReportTask`. If you create other tasks of the same type, they have the same capabilities.